# TFSOnline: the connection was unexpectedly closed by the server

Tags: azure, team-foundation-server, visual-studio

We are having a persistent issue with our Visual studio online development environment.

Scenario:

- Connect to the same team project in Visual Studio, with different accounts, on different PCs (but on the same LAN, so with the same public IP).
- Do a get latest, view history, check-in, no matter what on both of the PCs
- Do a get latest, view history, check-in, no matter what on one of the PCs
- The error from the screenshot occurs.

Any idea what the reason is for this issue? I've checked Wireshark, and it seems a lot of 'FIN-ACK' packets and RST packets are being sent, but I could not trace any of these packets down to the issue.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a proxy server in between?

Comment: No, connections go directly (LAN - router - TFS). No intercepting proxy has been configured.

Comment: Have you tried connecting to a dirty (no firewall) connection and seeing if that is the issue?

Comment: Do you have more than one internet connection? Maybe you could file out service provider.

Comment: @MrHinsh, difficult to test, because I would need to connect two machines to be able to replay the scenario described above. And I only have one internet connection, which means I need some kind of router in between..

Comment: Can you try a different router?

Comment: @MrHinsh, hmm I could try that, but not during the week. In any case, we have never had issues with this router. Could I see something in a packet trace?